# Bulk removing unwanted parts of images

Tags: python

I have downloaded a number of images (1000) from a website but they each have a black and white ruler running along 1 or 2 edges and some have these catalogue number tickets. I need these elements removed, the ruler at the very least.
Example images of coins:

[image: 1] [image: 2]

The images all have the ruler in slightly different places so i cant just preform the same crop on them.

So I tried to remove the black and replace it with white using this code

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = Image.open('image-0.jpg')
im = im.convert('RGBA')

data = np.array(im)   # "data" is a height x width x 4 numpy array
red, green, blue, alpha = data.T # Temporarily unpack the bands for readability

# Replace black with white
black_areas = (red < 150) & (blue < 150) & (green < 150)
data[..., :-1][black_areas.T] = (255, 255, 255) # Transpose back needed

im2 = Image.fromarray(data)
im2.show()
```

but it pretty much just removed half the coin as well:

[image: 3]

I was having a read of some posts on [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) but though I'd see if there was a simpler way I'd missed first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have taken a look at your problem and I have found a solution for your two images you provided, I hope it works for you other images as well but it is always hard to tell as it can be different on an individual basis. This solution is using OpenCV for preprocessing and contour detection to get the 2nd and 3rd largest elements in your picture (largest is the bounding box around the edges) which should be your coins. Then I create a box around those two items and add some padding before I crop to size.

So we start off with preprocessing:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(r'<PATH TO YOUR IMAGE>')
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=3, fy=3)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray, (5, 5), 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Still rather basic, we make the image bigger so it is easier to detect contours, then we turn it into grayscale, blur it and apply thresholding to it so we turn all grey values either white or black. This then gives us the following image:

[image: Thresholding]

We now do contour detection, get the areas around our contours and sort them by the biggest area. Then we drop the biggest one as it is the box around the whole image and take the 2nd and 3rd biggest. And then get the x,y,w,h values we are interested in.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

areas = []
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    areas.append((area, cnt))

areas.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
areas.pop(0)

x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(areas[0][1])
x2, y2, w2, h2 = cv2.boundingRect(areas[1][1])
```

If we draw a rectangle around those contours:
[image]

Now we take those coordinates and create a box around both of them. This might need some minor adjusting as I just quickly took the bigger width of the two and not the corresponding one for the right coin but since I added extra padding it should be fine in most cases. And finally crop to size:

```
pad = 15
img = img[(min(y, y2) - pad) : (max(y, y2) + max(h, h2) + pad),
    (min(x, x2) - pad) : (max(x, x2) + max(w, w2) + pad)]
```

[image]

I hope this helps you to understand how you could achieve what you want, I tried it on both your images and it worked well for them. It might need some adjustments and depending on how your other images look the simple approach of taking the two biggest objects (apart from image bounding box) might be turned into something more sophisticated to detect the cricular shapes or something along those lines. Alternatively you could try to detect the rulers and crop from their position inwards. You will have to decide after you have done this on more example images in your dataset.

Comment: Brilliant! thanks very much. looks to work for the majority of my images. Has issues with when there is only one coin is present. just because of the cropping? but was thinking of removing them from my data set anyways.  How would i adapt the code for running though all images in the folder - using Glob?

Comment: @lukehooper you could just use the `os` package. There's the `os.listdir()` function, which should be enough for you.

Comment: @lukehooper If you have images with only one coin you would need to only get the x,y,w,h value in my examplle for the first item and crop to them with `img[y:y+h, x:x+w]`. You can determine if you have two or one coin by calculating the difference between areas[0][0] and areas[1][0] as your coins should have roughly the same size if the difference between 2nd and 3rd largest object is tooo big you could assume only one coin is present. As for walking through the directory look into @Gabriel Jablonski 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a robust solution, you should try something like Max Kaha's response, since it'll provide you with greater fine tuning.

Since the rulers tend to be left with just a little bit of text after your "black to white" filter, a quick solution is to use erosion followed by a dilation to create a mask for your images, and then apply the mask to the original image.

Pillow offers that with the `ImageFilter` class. Here's your code with a few modifications that'll achieve that:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

WHITE = 255, 255, 255
input_image = Image.open('image.png')
input_image = input_image.convert('RGBA')

input_data = np.array(input_image)   # "data" is a height x width x 4 numpy array
red, green, blue, alpha = input_data.T # Temporarily unpack the bands for readability

# Replace black with white
thresh = 30
black_areas = (red < thresh) & (blue < thresh) & (green < thresh)
input_data[..., :-1][black_areas.T] = WHITE # Transpose back needed

erosion_factor = 5
# dilation is bigger to avoid cropping the objects of interest
dilation_factor = 11

erosion_filter = ImageFilter.MaxFilter(erosion_factor)
dilation_filter = ImageFilter.MinFilter(dilation_factor)

eroded = Image.fromarray(input_data).filter(erosion_filter)
dilated = eroded.filter(dilation_filter)

mask_threshold = 220
# the mask is black on regions to be hidden
mask = dilated.convert('L').point(lambda x: 255 if x < mask_threshold else 0)

# create base image
output_image = Image.new('RGBA', input_image.size, WHITE)
# paste only the desired regions
output_image.paste(input_image, mask=mask)

output_image.show()
```

[image: Output for first image] [image: Output for second image]

You should also play around with the black to white threshold and the erosion/dilation factors to try and find the best fit for most of your images.